# Rails form params don't have "params" key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My form is posting to the correct route as a PATCH request, but instead of having a "params" key in the `ActionController::Parameters` it has a key with the path the form was invoked from, here is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for applicants_profile_path, method: :patch do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

When my controller gets the request the params have a url rather then "params"

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", 
  "_method"=>"patch", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"BI...f0EDQ==", 
  "/dashboard/profile"=>{
    "first_name"=>"dfasfdsafs", 
  }, 
  "commit"=>"submit", 
  "controller"=>"applicants/profile", 
  "action"=>"update"} permitted: false>
```

Why is this? Rather than `/dashboard/profile` it should be `params` correct?

I should also say this route is a "resource" route like this:

```
resource :applicant, only: [ :show, :update ], as: :profile, path: 'profile', controller: 'profile'
```

Comment: The method is patch, which generally contains object Id in params which is being used for update record.

Comment: or may an issue of `simple_form_for`

Answer (score 1):

The answer actually seems to be related to how simple_form works with routes for singular resources, the answer was to add `url: applicants_profile_path` to my form helper:

```
<%= simple_form_for @applicant, url: applicants_profile_path, method: :patch do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in an object in simple form for example:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username %>
  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

I imagine yours should be:

```
<%= simple_form_for @applicant, method: :patch do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Or

```
<%= simple_form_for applicants_profile_path(@applicant), method: :patch do |f| %>
#... you get the idea
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to explain in my first comment on question.

Comment: updated my question, this won't work for me, I get this in my params now: `/dashboard/profile.30f4511d-aa58-474b-8a0c-018addd917eb`